# {discord.py} Delete a specific message from a specific user

Tags: discord, message, discord.py

I want to delete a specific message from a specific user using discord.py
The user's id is: 462616472754323457
The message that he can't send: lmao
So if he sends lmao, it deletes the message and send "You can't do that <@462616472754323457>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`discord.TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge).

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if len(await message.channel.purge(limit=200, check=lambda x: ('lmao' in x.content.strip().lower()) and x.author.id == 462616572754323457)) > 0:
        await message.channel.send('You are not allowed to do that, <@462616572754323457>')
```

Accounting for when the bot is offline, the bot will check 200 messages before the current message and delete any that are from `462616572754323457` and have `'lmao'` in the contents. (You can further enhance this by using `re`.)

Comment: What happened? Is there any exceptions? Keep in mind that this only works if the sender has ID 462616572754323457. If you want it for everyone, try changing `x.author.id == 462616572754323457` in the code to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on_message` event, which triggers whenever a message is sent.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message) # add this if also using command decorators
    if message.author.id == 462616472754323457 and "lmao" in message.content.lower():
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"You can't do that, {message.author.mention}")
```

---

**References:**

- [`discord.on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)
- [`Message.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete)
- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)
- [`Member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention)

Comment: @SP73 Did it throw an error? Would you be able to edit your question with the code you tried?

Comment: @SP73 Please could you edit in the code into your question that you currently have in your program. It could be a simple typo or something that you're missing.